# How to prevent google ad from showing below the footer of my theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, blogs, adsense

I applied the adsence code on my website but the ad is also showing below the theme footer(on desktop as well as mobile)
I searched online but not a single relevant thread.

How to resolve?

Comment: You need to supply more information. Like where did you place the code i.e. widget area, template file etc. Please also supply a link for more clarity.

Comment: One code i placed on the sidebar widget. and one page level ad code on the theme header. my website www.notesforsapiens.com

Comment: If you are using a plugin to add the ads please check it

Comment: I am not using any plugin for ads. For one code i used the text block in widget area and for another code I used the header plugin (as in my genesis theme I cant find header file).